# Golang templating does not work properly

Tags: go, templating

I have an if else block in my template. when `else if` is true it is rendered always empty as if `else` or `else if` is not there 
[image]

here is my template

[image: in this case]
in this case, it renders nothing 
[image]

And also I am using `text/template` because `html/template`  send the page completely empty

```
//the template
    <script>
                  {{if.PassChange}}
                  swal("{{.Lang.Success}}", "{{.Lang.PleaseLogin}}", "success")
                  {{end}}
                  {{if.UserExists}}
                  swal("{{.Lang.Fail}}", "{{.Lang.AlreadyMember}}", "error")
                  {{end}}
    </script>




//rendering part
    BasePath.Get("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        tpl.ExecResponse(w, struct{Lang map[string]string ; UserExists bool}{Lang:lang.GetLang(r),UserExists:true})
    })
```

Comment: The images and particularly the second are difficult to read. Please paste the text into the question.  Also, what library are you using to render the template?

Comment: @MellowMarmot just updated

Comment: the smart people of the galaxy who voted negative would you please share your incredible knowledge with us why you think this is a stupid question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you print the error from executing the template, you will find that the template cannot evaluate the field `PassChange`.  One possible fix is to add a PassChange field to the struct.

```
tpl.ExecResponse(w, struct{PassChange bool; Lang map[string]string ; UserExists bool}{Lang:lang.GetLang(r),UserExists:true})
```